# convert XML to JSON using PHP/JQuery- response should be in JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, json, cross-domain

All, i have to make a call to third party service where it will return the response in XML, due to that i am not able to access the XML. is there any way to convert the XML response to json so that i can use in my project

i have tried this but i don't want to hard code my response

```
// Given an XML string
def xml = '''<root>
            |    <node>Tim</node>
            |    <node>Tom</node>
            |    <node>
            |      <anotherNode>another</anotherNode>
            |    </node>
            |</root>'''.stripMargin()

// Parse it
def parsed = new XmlParser().parseText( xml )

// Deal with each node:
def handle
handle = { node ->
  if( node instanceof String ) {
      node
  }
  else {
      [ (node.name()): node.collect( handle ) ]
  }
}
// Convert it to a Map containing a List of Maps
def jsonObject = [ (parsed.name()): parsed.collect { node ->
   [ (node.name()): node.collect( handle ) ]
} ]

// And dump it as Json
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder( jsonObject )

// Check it's what we expected
assert json.toString() == '{"root":[{"node":["Tim"]},{"node":["Tom"]},{"node":[{"anotherNode":["another"]}]}]}'
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vikky, I had similar issue like this 
here is the code for your requirement, Place this code in PHP file say xmltojson.php

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
if(strlen($_GET["feed"])>2) 
{ 
    $xml = file_get_contents(urldecode($_GET["feed"])); 
    if($xml) 
    { 
        $data = @simplexml_load_string($xml, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA); 
        $json = json_encode($data); 
        echo isset($_GET["callback"]) ? "{$_GET[�callback�]}($json)" : $json; 
    } 
}
?>
```

JQuery code :

```
/* Accessing the thirdparty data feed,converted xml to json using php and assigned the data to the model */
    $.getJSON("xmltojson.php",{feed:"http://www.someurl.com/registerlistxml.asp?m=313"},function(data){
        //put your code to access the json data 
    });
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Naveen this is what i am expecting. well done.